# How duplicates should be handled when duplicated gets a neither accepted nor upvoted answer?

Tags: discussion, support

[Latest example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/763322/how-to-cancel-several-jobs-based-on-the-job-name)

- Question A (most reasonably) gets an answer as part of question B.
- However, question B 's answer is neither accepted nor upvoted.

My close duplicate request cannot be accepted.

What should be done ?

- Upvote question B's answer and close duplicate (request) question A ? (Being said that, while judging the answer perfectly reasonable, I do not get here & now the means to test the solution) ?
- Post a comment as I did and let it be ?

**EDIT :** The situation reoccurred in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/765395/how-do-you-type-special-characters-in-the-logging-prompt).
This one being even less obvious since the suggested answer had not been working in several cases.
In both case we can observe that Stephen authoritatively closed duplicate after (having ? / the answer of the duplicated being ?) upvoted.
This suggesting an additional alternative :

- Leave that to hammer holders ?

---

All this leading incidentally to another ? (Or is it the real ?) question :

Is it actually pertinent to submit a close duplicate request to the condition of the duplicated having an upvoted or accepted answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s start with your last question:

> Is it actually pertinent to submit a close duplicate request to the condition of the duplicated having an upvoted or accepted answer?

I think it is, as long as the existing voting system works. Usually, a useful answer should attract upvotes, and thus become usable when suggesting a duplicate. The general assumption is that a post with no upvotes isn’t useful.

This obviously starts failing when fewer people vote, as is the case now, or for niche questions where few people are able to upvote meaningfully (including the question’s author, who may not have enough reputation to upvote and may not understand the benefits of accepting an answer).

Getting to your initial question then, in such circumstances I think both approaches you suggest are valid, if you follow the expected practice. If you can meaningfully upvote question B’s answer, then do so, and suggest it as an answer for question A. If you can’t, then leave a comment pointing to it — that way, question A’s author might get an answer (which is the main purpose of the site, really), and they might upvote it themselves if they can. The comment might also attract other readers’ attention to the potential answer, which they may not have noticed before but may be qualified to upvote too.

Comment: Your wiseness is definitely of the same level than your contributions on this site. Thank you. I was absurdly trying to help the questions' author and in the same time tidy-up Augeas' stables. These tasks cannot obviously be undertaken concurrently and I'll go with you considering helping questions' authors is the main purpose. Not to say that cheating (as, in my personal case it would have been had I upvoted the duplicated's answer) a broken system is of no help at all. And BTW : Merry Christmas to you Stephen.

Comment: Thank you, merry Christmas to you too!